# How do I stop the code from stopping

Tags: rpi.gpio

When I run the code

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from gpiozero import Button
button = Button(21)
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522

reader = SimpleMFRC522()

id, text = reader.read()
if (text == "benfica"):
    button.wait_for_press
    print("hello")
```

the code will just stop and not wait for me to press the button. How do I stop it from doing this? Thanks.

Comment: This is a general programming question.  Not Pi specific.

Comment: sorry didnt know

Comment: There are many things wrong with this code. Basically it is doing what YOU asked it to do. You are mixing 2 libraries pick one. I suggest you read the examples on the gpiozero site.